# How to invoke scull_open() in user-space, where scull_open is defined in scull kernel driver

Tags: c, linux

I am newbie to Linux device driver programming. I am just trying to use the scull driver which is explained in Linux Device Drivers.

Would like to invoke the `scull_open()` from user-space for write/read or close operations.

Currently I'm able to insert the scull module successfully using insmod and got the major number too. I also got the dev node `/dev/scull0` using mknod /dev/scull0 c 251 0.

Next i used the below statement to open my newly created scull device

```
file_d = scull_open("/dev/scull0", 0);
```

But I got the following error:

```
undefined reference to `scull_open'
```

I used gcc for compilation.

> Do I need to link any library or header files to make use of scull driver?
>   Please explain how should i open scull driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to link any library or header files to make use of scull driver?

**No you do NOT need to use any additional libraries/headers to make this work.**

---

In the example **scull driver** from **[LDD3 book](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/)**, `scull_open()` is the handler function that is implemented to handle the `open()` call from user-space on the `/dev/scull0` device.

Please go ahead and update your userspace app to

```
file_d = open("/dev/scull0", 0);
```

When running the updated app, if the module is insmod-ed and `/dev/scull0` exists, executing the above line will result in `scull_open()` being called within your Linux kernel driver module immediately.

> So how does `open()` end up calling `scull_open()` ?

Remember `scull_fops()` within your scull driver code?

Defined as...

```
struct file_operations scull_fops = {
    .owner =    THIS_MODULE,
    .llseek =   scull_llseek,
    .read =     scull_read,
    .write =    scull_write,
    .unlocked_ioctl =    scull_ioctl,
    .open =     scull_open,
    .release =  scull_release,
};
```

and used as...

```
cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops);
```

The above steps essentially associate the various functions listed within `scull_fops` with the scull device (eg. `/dev/scull0`).

Specifically, `scull_open()` is associated with `open()`. In other words,

- `scull_open()`
- is registered as the **handler** to `open()`
- within the scull driver.

> 1. In user-space, the call to `open()` is seen by the Linux kernel.
> 2. The kernel checks for the driver responsible for creating the
>      `/dev/scull0` device.
> 3. Next the kernel checks to see which is the function handler
>      registered to handle open within the scull driver and calls it; in
>      this case `scull_open()`.

---

<sub>1. On a side-note, it is always a good idea to use the relevant macros/enums to clarify the context/intent. For example, use `O_RDONLY` instead of `0` as the 2nd parameter to the call to `open()`.</sub>

<sub>2. Also FYI, since you are following the LDD3 book, here is a list of [unconfirmed](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596005900) / [confirmed](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596005900) mistakes in the book.</sub>

Comment: I think I end up with actual problem now. Now, I get the error as "No such device or address". What does it mean?

Comment: The error message `No such device or address` means that somewhere in the Linux kernel the code is returning [`-ENXIO`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L9); most likely from within [`chrdev_open()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/char_dev.c#L344). Please share the exact code of your scull driver and steps you followed so that anyone interested can reproduce the issue and pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Yeah..I can able to invoke open() through application layer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment "most likely from within chrdev_open()". The error is in my device code in which I accidentally defined a macro with value 0. Then I used that macro in the condition of for() loop to associate my device number to kernel structure using cdev_add(). I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @anbu Glad to help. Good that you explained the root-cause of the error. It will help others who stumble upon this question when google-ing this error. Since the issue in this question is resolved, please go ahead and mark this answer as accepted. ❄️ Merry Christmas ❄️

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for similar problems, and finally I'm done with code. And here is implementation source https://github.com/pkumarg/scull if someone needs it further.